# SQL - Running Total - Year To Date, Previous Year To Date, and Last Rolling 12 Months

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Thanks for helping me out with this one!  I apologize in advance for the formatting, but I think it is easy to follow.

Provided is a sample table of data.  I need three separate columns created with query language.  The running total must go consider the ID and the date.

Running 12 Months - I need sum the value of each ID for rolling 12 months.

Current YTD - Sum the value of each ID for the current year of the date of the value.

Previous YTD - Sum the value of each ID for the year immediately prior to the date of the value.

THANK YOU!

CURRENT TABLE

```
ID  DATE        VALUE
S1  01/01/2015  5
S1  02/01/2015  5
S1  03/01/2015  5
S1  04/01/2015  5
S1  05/01/2015  5
S1  06/01/2015  5
S1  07/01/2015  5
S1  08/01/2015  5
S1  09/01/2015  5
S1  10/01/2015  5
S1  11/01/2015  5
S1  12/01/2015  5
S1  01/01/2016  5
S2  01/01/2015  10
S2  02/01/2015  10
S2  03/01/2015  10
S2  04/01/2015  10
S2  05/01/2015  10
S2  06/01/2015  10
S2  07/01/2015  10
S2  08/01/2015  10
S2  09/01/2015  10
S2  10/01/2015  10
S2  11/01/2015  10
S2  12/01/2015  10
S2  01/01/2016  10
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
ID  DATE            VALUE   Running12   CalendarYTD PrevCalendarYTD
S1  01/01/2015      5       5           5   
S1  02/01/2015      5       10          10  
S1  03/01/2015      5       15          15  
S1  04/01/2015      5       20          20  
S1  05/01/2015      5       25          25  
S1  06/01/2015      5       30          30  
S1  07/01/2015      5       35          35  
S1  08/01/2015      5       40          40  
S1  09/01/2015      5       45          45  
S1  10/01/2015      5       50          50  
S1  11/01/2015      5       55          55  
S1  12/01/2015      5       60          60  
S1  01/01/2016      5       60          5              5
S2  01/01/2015      10      10          10  
S2  02/01/2015      10      20          20  
S2  03/01/2015      10      30          30  
S2  04/01/2015      10      40          40  
S2  05/01/2015      10      50          50  
S2  06/01/2015      10      60          60  
S2  07/01/2015      10      70          70  
S2  08/01/2015      10      80          80  
S2  09/01/2015      10      90          90  
S2  10/01/2015      10      100         100
S2  11/01/2015      10      110         110 
S2  12/01/2015      10      120         10  
S2  01/01/2016      10      120         10              10
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - and 'sql' is very generic. Perhaps there's some dialect of sql that you are using.

Comment: Hi Strawberry - I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Unless I did something wrong, I tried to attach a very helpful image but could not.  My reputation points aren't high enough (new user).  So, I did the best I could and attached the data in the text of the message.

Comment: are there any missing dates in the table? and what should the result be in that case?

Comment: What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: Images are rarely helpful

Comment: Thanks, John for fixing my format!

Comment: Mike - I have tried multiple things, but there are some nuances and tricks of the trade, and I'm not quite there yet  I tried SUM / OVER.  I tried bookending the data, so to speak, with DATEFROMPARTS.  It all seemed very inelegant, time consuming, and like I needed some help.

Comment: @GBOHNC: Edit your question. Include the code you tried, and how it failed. As it stands, it doesn't look like you tried anything, and you just want someone to write your code for you.

Comment: Mike - I know what you are saying, and you are wrong.  I put a lot of time into it. In many ways, I'm an average programmer and still learning the ropes. I am not going to post my code because it is inelegant, and not nearly as good as John's solution. I don't want to crud up the stream with bad code. One of the things I dislike about searching for solutions is that my search engine hits bring up all kinds of failed efforts that don't help at all. So, I'm going to leave John's answer as the best solution. If someone stumbles upon it with a search engine, then they will have the BEST solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **VKP Raised a valid point.  If missing months, we would need to fill.**

The following will generate your running total columns.

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,Running12       = sum(Value) over (Partition By ID Order By Date Rows Between 11 Preceding and Current Row)
      ,CalendarYTD     = sum(Value) over (Partition By ID,Year(Date) Order By Date)
      ,PrevCalendarYTD = case when month(date)<>1 then null else (Select Value from @YourTable Where ID=A.ID and date=dateadd(year,-1,A.date)) end
 From @YourTable A
 Order By ID,Date
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: @vkp  Good catch - I had 12 months in my head and typed 12.  Will fix.

Comment: @GBOHNC Happy to help.  It is well worth your time to get comfortable with the window functions.  They can be invaluable!

Comment: One more thing - I need the PrevCalendarYTD to be just like CalendarYTD, but just the previous year.  My bad if I misled you.  I've been messing with it for a couple hours.  I'm having trouble making the previous calendar calculation.  I took the formula from CalendarYTD, but I am not successfully incorporating it into a Window Function.

PrevCalendarYTD = (Select Value from @YourTable Where ID=A.ID and date=dateadd(year,-1,A.date)) end

I must be just overlooking something, but it's not working for me.

Comment: OK - I think I figured out the PrevCalendarYTD.

SUM(((SELECT Value FROM MYTable WHERE ID=A.ID and Date=DATEADD(YEAR,-1,A.Date)))) over (Partition By ID,YEAR(Date) Order By Date)

Thoughts?

Comment: By the way, I've upvoted a few comments on here.  I'm a newbie, and my reputation points are too low for them to count.  So, just an FYI.  You've been given credit for your input, but it isn't counting or displaying because my rep score is still too low (newbie status).

THANKS!